# How to run lengthy tasks from an ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I've got an ASP.NET page with a simple form. The user fills out the form with some details, uploads a document, and some processing of the file then needs to happens on the server side.

My question is - what's the best approach to handling the server side processing of the files? The processing involves calling an exe. Should I use seperate threads for this?

Ideally I want the user to submit the form without the web page just hanging there while the processing takes place.

I've tried this code but my task never runs on the server:

```
Action<object> action = (object obj) =>
{
      // Create a .xdu file for this job
       string xduFile = launcher.CreateSingleJobBatchFile(LanguagePair, SourceFileLocation);

      // Launch the job                 
      launcher.ProcessJob(xduFile);
};

Task job = new Task(action, "test");
job.Start();
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could invoke the processing functionality asynchronously in a classic **fire and forget** fashion:

**In .NET 4.0** you should do this using the new [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Do work
});
```

If you need to pass an argument to the action delegate you could do it like this:

```
Action<object> task = args =>
{
    // Do work with args
};    
Task.Factory.StartNew(task, "SomeArgument");
```

**In .NET 3.5 and earlier** you would instead do it this way:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(args =>
{
   // Do work
});
```

**Related resources:**

- [Task Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)
- [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx)

Comment: I've tried using a similar approach but my task never runs on the server, I've added the code my question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jimmy: Can you try either of the two suggestions above?

Comment: @mellamokb - I get a NullReferenceException when I use the second one, nothing happens with the first, i.e. no exception and the processing doesn't happen.

Comment: @Jimmy: Does the code you are trying to run work fine if you don't run it as a background task?  Are you passing in all the data that is needed to process?  Maybe some sample code would help if it's not too big.

Comment: NullReferanceException happens on this line - _"string xduFileLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/JobSpace/" + xduFileName);"_ - should Server.MapPath still work in this context?

Comment: @Jimmy: `HttpContext.Current` may not exist in the new thread.  You can pass that path in as a parameter.

Comment: You should pass the `xduFileLocation` value as a parameter to the Task delegate since the HttpContext is not guaranteed to be there in the execution context of the Task.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys - that was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => MyFunc(arg0, arg1, ...));
```

Where MyFunc() does the server-side processing in the background after the user submits the page;

Answer (score 1):

I have a site that does some potentially long running stuff that needs to be responsive and update a timer for the user.

My solution was to build a state machine into the page with a hidden value and some session values.

I have these on my aspx side:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1600" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnASynchStatus" Value="" />
```

And my code looks something like:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    PostbackStateEngineStep()
    UpdateElapsedTime()
End Sub

Private Sub PostbackStateEngineStep()
    If hdnASynchStatus.Value = "" And Not CBool(Session("WaitingForCallback")) Then

        Dim i As IAsyncResult = {...run something that spawns in it's own thread, and calls ProcessCallBack when it's done...}

        Session.Add("WaitingForCallback", True)
        Session.Add("InvokeTime", DateTime.Now)
        hdnASynchStatus.Value = "WaitingForCallback"
    ElseIf CBool(Session("WaitingForCallback")) Then
        If Not CBool(Session("ProcessComplete")) Then
            hdnASynchStatus.Value = "WaitingForCallback"
        Else
            'ALL DONE HERE
            'redirect to the next page now
            response.redirect(...)
        End If
    Else
        hdnASynchStatus.Value = "DoProcessing"
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub ProcessCallBack(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Session.Add("ProcessComplete", True)
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateElapsedTime()
    'update a label with the elapsed time
End Sub
```